# Change default browser screen font size

Tags: firefox, fonts, browser, size

Running Fedora 34, Xfce desktop.

When I run Firefox, the screen is always too small and I find that I'm constantly hitting the <kbd>Ctrl+</kbd> combination to set the screen size to 133% of the default so that I can read the pages.

How can I make this change happen by  default - i.e. every time I open a new window or tab, it'll be at that magic  (for me anyway) 133%? 133% corresponds to 3 <kbd>Ctrl+</kbd>s BTW. As my sight deteriorates, I might want more <kbd>Ctrl+</kbd>s, so a general answer would be appreciated!

I know about the Zoom functionality but that only appears to work on a per window/tab basis.

Comment: look in  Firefox settings

Answer (score 0):

1. about:preferences -> Zoom -> Default Zoom
2. about:config -> font.size.systemFontScale -> What you prefer (this breaks rare websites, i.e. Steam Forums)